# Toggle the mode in a vim function

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am trying to modify the following function:

```
function! changeNumber() abort
    if &nu + &rnu == 0
        set nopaste
        " how to set normal mode after the function exits?
    else
        set paste
        " how to set insert mode after the function exits?
    endif
endfunction
```

Basically, I'm trying to write a copy-paste helper function that removes the line numbers and enters/exits insert mode when it runs (for the full problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952187/651174).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:startinsert`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#%3Astartinsert) and [`:stopinsert`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#%3Astopinsert) here.

From `:help :startinsert`:

> Start Insert mode just after executing this command. Works like typing `i` in Normal mode.  When the `!` is included it works like `A`, append to the line. Otherwise insertion starts at the cursor position. Note that when using this command in a function or
>   script, the insertion only starts after the function or script is finished.

So your function snippet becomes:

```
function! changeNumber() abort
    if &nu + &rnu == 0
        set nopaste
        stopinsert
    else
        set paste
        startinsert
    endif
endfunction
```

While you might possibly consider using the `startinsert!` variant to append at the end of the line instead.